# CanvasJS Error: Chart Container with id "chartContainer1" was not found

Tags: angular, angular-material, canvasjs

I want to load canvasjs chart in angular material modal.But when i render the chart i got this error **CanvasJS Error: Chart Container with id "chartContainer1" was not found**
I added 3 image of my code below with error...

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

```
Try putting a delay in calling initChart('line'),
i.e 
setTimeout(() => {
    initChart('line');
}, 1000)
```